# How to exclude some text in echo

Tags: batch-file, command-line

How can I shorten output of this command.

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com > %~d0\bat\setup\ipaut\myip.txt
```

This gives me a text file:

```
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Name:    myip.opendns.com
Address:  84.48.190.45
```

What I actually want in the text file is the myip.opendns.com address.
Example

```
84.48.190.45
```

Comment: Will it always be in the same position in the file, or could the other opendns address possibly come first sometimes?

Comment: Yes. But the adress is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com') do (
   if not defined var (
      set "var=%%a"
   ) else (
      set "!var!=%%a"
      set "var="
   )
)

echo %myip.opendns.com%> output.txt
```

Comment: Excuse me. From this SomethingDark's question: "Will it always be in the same position in the file, or could the other opendns address possibly come first sometimes?" and your answer, I assumed that the text you want may change its position in the file, so my solution manage this case. Squashman's answer always returns the last line in the file. Perhaps I misunderstood something?

Comment: Tank you for the comment. That is a very good point. Corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%G in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com') do >myip.txt echo %%G
```

This parses the output of the nslookup command and outputs the result to a text file.